# Can't Push to Git Repository

Tags: xcode, git

I am trying to push my recent commits to a Git repository that I have set up on Bitbucket, and for some reason it never pushes.

Xcode just gets stuck on the screen saying "Pushing Changes..." and "Preparing to Push Changes..." but it never completes. Then ends with "The working copy of 'Master' is currently up to date."

But it's not.

I have made changes.

Also tried adding more commits, but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git doesn't always work with Xcode, usually because of the crap files Xcode generates (eg xcworkspace etc), and it's pretty buggy in general, so I would just try pushing from the command line instead of through Xcode (which should also give you a more detailed error message if it doesn't work).

Answer (score -1):

Try doing a git add and then git commit