# Cannot push to remote git repository

Tags: xcode, git, terminal

So I have been having troubles pushing my most recent commits to a remote repository that I have set up on Bitbucket.

I am originally using Xcode, and have asked [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963677/cant-push-to-git-repository) and was recommended to use terminal to push instead of Xcode.

Now, I tried terminal but that did not solve the problem. But it did give me a more detailed error message when I try `git push`

```
Neils-iMac:ProjectName Neil$ git push
Password: 

Counting objects: 49, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Writing objects: 100% (39/39), 975.78 KiB, done.
Total 39 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=55, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: expected ok/error, helper said '2004\??? ?&?ЇҶ-9?u?r?m?v?ǣ3Ƅ:??Eƒ?=?&?"d?+??
   *^?eA??/3cv????ʞe??f???????
                              ?(??`}D???5???^:T??PxP????%?338?]??F?}???Gf?g??[??*??}zƈ1X'

Neils-iMac:ProjectName Neil$ 
Neils-iMac:ProjectName Neil$
```

I am new to these remote repositories, and had everything working fine on Xcode, so if you recommend for me to do something in terminal it would help if you described how to do so.

See my [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963677/cant-push-to-git-repository) for a bit more detail.

---

**EDIT**: This is the result of;

`git status`:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   CrunchCalculator.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/
#   CrunchCalculator.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

`git remote show origin`:

```
HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

Comment: What's the output of `git status` and `git remote show origin`?

Comment: I will try this when I get home today, then get back to you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to push a large delta and your [push buffer is not big enough](http://flyingtomoon.com/2011/04/12/git-push-is-failed-due-to-rpc-failure-result56/)

Try this:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: Although I have pushed larger commits before

Comment: Strange. I had the same problem even with very small pushes and it worked if setting http.postBuffer as you mentioned. I never changed that value so I would really like to understand the problem.

Comment: I believe that specific number is relatively arbitrary.

From what I can tell the issue is that the data you're trying to commit (not necessarily the same as the deltas/changesets you're pushing, but the actual data that Git is pushing) is bigger than the default value.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` worked for me.